# How to get the number of touch inputs

Tags: java, android

I need to check how many user that touches the screen, and I thought I could use `event.getPointerCount` But now I only get 1 as the result in LogCat. If two fingers touch the screen, shouln't I get 2 as a result then? I would like to use this as an id for each user. Part of the code below is inside a touch event method.

```
        switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        gameLoop.touchDownX = event.getX();
        gameLoop.touchDownY = event.getY();

        // Check number of users
        for(int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount() && i < 2; i++) {
            id = event.getPointerCount();
        }

        // Test
        String num = Integer.toString(id);
        Log.i("User number : ", num);

        break;
```

Comment: if your device supports multitouch

Comment: @blackbelt Hmm, I have an Samsung Young that I bought one year ago. Don't all newer device support multitouch!?

Comment: Try to print in Log `event.getPointerCount();` before the switch statement. Do you get different results ?

Comment: @ZouZou I have tested that also, but I only got 1 in LogCat.

Comment: @3D-kreativ Coud you try to print `boolean hasMultitouch =         context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH);` and see if it's false or true please ?

Comment: And if your print getPointerCount before the switch you always get 1 ? Show the full onTouch method please.

Comment: @ZouZou Hmm, I don't know why, but it seems like it's working now! I have to test it a little bit more. But thanks for the help!